# Запрос и массовая вставка полученных значений

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь сделать выборку данных из БД и полученные значения записать в другую таблицу. При этом результат поиска - это только один столбец в таблице, которую нужно заполнить (`person_id`). Второй столбец нужно задать отдельно (`label_id`). Ниже я пытаюсь вставить в таблицу `label_person` данные: `label_id=8`, `person_id` - результат поиска. Однако получаю ошибку

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db7`.`label_person`, CONSTRAINT `FK_label_person_label_id` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`label_id`) REFERENCES `labels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

Код запроса

```
INSERT INTO label_person (label_id, person_id)
  SELECT
    8,
    people.id
  FROM people
    INNER JOIN answers
      ON answers.person_id = people.id
    INNER JOIN samples
      ON samples.person_id = people.id
    INNER JOIN prefixes
      ON samples.prefix_id = prefixes.id
  WHERE (answers.question_id = 2 AND answers.value >= 2)
  OR (answers.question_id = 4 AND answers.value = 0)
  GROUP BY people.id,
           people.surname,
           prefixes.name,
           samples.number
  HAVING COUNT(people.id) >= 2
```

Код таблицы `label_person`

```
CREATE TABLE `label_person` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `label_person_unique` (`label_id`,`person_id`),
  KEY `FK_label_person_person_id` (`person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_label_person_label_id` FOREIGN KEY (`label_id`) REFERENCES `labels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_label_person_person_id` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `people` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=262 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Как можно получить данные одним запросом, а потом вставить их в другую таблицу, задав для нужных полей нужные значения?

Comment: покажите код ключа для таблицы `label_person`

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Добавил

Comment: в `labels` есть id=8?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis оформите, пожалуйста, ответ

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, Вы пытаетесь вставить в таблицу ID, которой нет в таблице `labels`. В результате срабатывает ограничение ключа `FK_label_person_label_id`, который отвечает за эту проверку.

Comment: Спасибо! Через 6 минут приму ответ.